# SwiftUI: Clear TextField on edit begin

Tags: swiftui, textfield

How can I clear the content of TextField when editing begin.

I've try to read Apple Document and search all the similar question and cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 6):

In code it would look like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct MyTextView: View {
    @State private var text1: String = "Some Content"
    @State private var text1Placeholder: String = ""
    @State private var text2: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: HorizontalAlignment.center, spacing: 20) {

            Image(systemName: "circle")
            TextField( self.$text1Placeholder.wrappedValue, text: $text1, onEditingChanged: { (editing) in
                if editing {
                    self.$text1Placeholder.wrappedValue
                        = self.$text1.wrappedValue 
                    self.$text1.wrappedValue = ""
                }
            })
            TextField("Text Field 2", text: $text2)
            .border(Color.green)

        }.padding()

    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: MyTextView())
```

Comment: And how can I show the current value of text1 as the placeHolder of the TextField after setting the self.text1 = ""

Comment: I edited my answer related to your additional question.

Answer (score 2):

The onEditingChange parameter take a closure with a single Bool parameter, if it is true then the TextField has begun to edit the parameter. In your closure check the value of the parameter and clear the TextField variable if it is true.